# Opengl object looking at another object

Tags: opengl, position

I would like to get angle between object and another object. This must be vertical and horizontal angle.

I Have the coordinates of:

```
posX, posY, posZ 
objectX, objectY, objectZ
```

I tried:

```
glRotatef( atan2(objectY - posY,objectX - posX)* 180.0f / 3.14f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glRotatef( atan2(objectZ - posZ,objectX - posX)* 180.0f / 3.14f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
```

but sometime don't working correctly

Comment: I'd suggest using a `#define` for PI instead of hardcoding 3.14 - look for `M_PI` or some other reasonably standard C/C++ implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, if you just have two "objects," there's no angle between them. You need a frame of reference.

For example, two points in 2-D don't have an angle between them. If you treat one as the origin, however, you're probably going to want to measure the angle between the second point and the **x-axis**.

Similarly, in 3-D, you need to have a frame of reference. You won't actually get 1 angle, but 2. One angle goes around the **z-axis** by 2PI, and the second goes up and down (angle from the **xy-plane**) PI. Check out [Spherical Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) to get a good explanation.

With this in mind, you want to:

1. Translate your first object to the origin.
2. Translate your second object by the same amount.
3. Convert the second object's position from cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates. That link will help.

But wait! What if you care about the orientation of that first object? EG, it's a character looking some direction. You probably want that angle to be dependent on which way he's looking. If he's looking right at it, you probably want 0 radians (0 degrees), and if it's behind him, you probably want PI radians (180 degrees).

The process is the same as above, but you first must transform that second object from world space into "character" space - that coordinate system relevant to that first object. It's mathematically the same as transforming something into camera space. From there just convert the new position of your object from cartesian to spherical coordinates to get your angles.

**Suggestions**

- Don't hardcore π into your code. Use a `#define`, preferably from a standard or very widely used library.
- Don't use the Fixed Function Pipeline. It has been deprecated for I think ~8 years now. It is slow and not customizable.
- If you're having a tough time with rotation, it's probably because you're letting OpenGL do it for you. Manage your own rotation matrix. Then you know exactly what you're doing.
- You shouldn't need `glRotatef` to find the angle anyway. OpenGL is just for drawing. Given two objects, you should be able to figure out the angle between them without making any calls to OpenGL. In fact, you *shouldn't* call OpenGL.